# Flask post/redirect/get pattern cannot recover from an error

Tags: python, flask

I have an error recovery problem in a Flask view function. Its simplified version is here:

```
@app.route('/log', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def elog():
    form = LogForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flask.session['logformdata'] = form.data
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('elog'))

    try:
        formdata = flask.session.pop('logformdata')
    except KeyError:
        return flask.render_template('log.html', form=form)

    log = ... # result of a query
    form.process(data=formdata)
    return flask.render_template('log.html', form=form, log=log)
```

The important part is that it implements the post/redirect/get pattern and stores the form data between POST and GET in the `flask.session` storage which is implemented with HTTP cookies.

Now let's assume there is a bug somewhere and the function crashes with certain input. Of course, it should not happen. But when it does, the user's experience is terrible.

In detail:

- the user posts a form (POST)
- the form data is stored in the `flask.session`, i.e. as a cookie
- after a redirect, the function is called again (GET), but now it crashes unexpectedly. The user sees some error message. That is not good, but bugs happen.
- the user reloads the page intending to start over, but gets the same error repeated again and again!

The key point is that the statement `flask.session.pop` removes the form data from the `session` storage, but when the function crashes, the corresponding cookie remains in the user's browser. Each reload triggers the bug again. Restarting the browser may help (depending on `session.permanent` flag). The only guaranteed remedy is to manually delete the cookie from the browser. This effectively makes the webpage unusable.

I think I can mitigate the problem with setting a very short cookie lifetime (15 seconds or so) or by generating a new secret key after each restart. I did not try it and it is definitely not a good solution if session cookie contains other data.

How can I make functions like the one above more robust?

Comment: I don't fully understand your issue, but I don't think you're doing post/redirect/get correctly. Your "redirect" is actually to the same page, I'm pretty sure the idea of P/R/G is to do whatever is needed with the form data, then redirect to a *different* page, usually with some sort of flash message saying "your data was submitted" or whatever. (An error with the form should lead to the page with the form being reloaded, with the errors highlighted.)

Comment: I had something similar going on in my code - I settled for ignoring it and creating fewer errors, but in some places I have a catch all exceptions-thing which "restarts" and sends the user to another place, earlier in the form chain. But I think I am vulnerable to exactly what you describe...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "The user sees some error message"? How are you handling errors?

Comment: @dylanj.nz In this case there was an obscure bug unnoticed for two or more years. It was triggered by an unusual combination of factors not anticipated before and caused a crash (raised exception). The user sees only an "internal server error" message. Please note that my question is not about any particular error or message. The problem is that a small annoyance (one user's query not processed properly) gets amplified into a large problem (user cannot use the service at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no way to handle the error within the view itself, my approach would be to [register an error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/errorhandling/#registering) for the entire app, and manage the session within here i.e. reset to a default/safe state.

Example:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def handle_internal_server_error(ex):
    """Handle an unexpected and uncaught (500) server error."""

    # Reset session here & display error (e.g. flash or other)

    return  # redirect or render
```

Comment: I had to replace `@app.errorhandler(500)` with `@app.errorhandler(Exception)`, then it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your simplified example misses an important bit representing what exactly crashes.

If some piece of the logic can crash unexpectedly you should expect for it to do so and handle these cases. For example, by wrapping it in a usual `try/catch` and removing the session cookie within the catch block.

Comment: _"If some piece of the logic can crash unexpectedly you should expect for it "_ That's a contradiction IMO.

Comment: @VPfB poor wording perhaps, apologies for that. What i meant to say is you should try and identify which bit crashes and handle these cases.

Comment: Fair enough. As I wrote in other comment lately, this bug existed unnoticed for several years until it manifested itself really unexpectedly. Then it was really easy to find and correct. The real problem was that the user was unable to enter any other query after that one single query that failed. How to avoid such a big negative consequence of a small error that happened only once in few years is the core of my question. Of course writing bug-free perfect code would make it a non-issue, but we do not live in an ideal world.

Answer (score 0):

You are managing the session manually and that is causing this issue. Please look into implementing [Message Flashing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/) in your application. You can customize flashes to use server side session or even use cookies. Flash messages can be maintained across multiple pages even with redirects as well.

Comment: this is not aboutjust presenting messages to the user - and, of course, it is on a level it has to be handled manually.

Comment: And should you always handle it using the session? Can't you just set a boolean  and pass it to the template (Which will render the error on top of the form based on the boolean)?

Comment: Something like `return flask.render_template('log.html', form=form, error=True)` and within the log.html, you can have a check on this error var and display the error div if it is True.

Comment: @mbhargav294 It is really not about messages. The Flask sessions object I'm talking about is described here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#sessions I'm using it for the purpose it is provided, i.e. for storing information from one request to another. I added a new comment under the question in response to dylan.jz, please read.